# Django Serializer - Returning Specific Fields

Tags: json, django, orm, django-rest-framework

I want to return a specific field from my model, a field that, for example, has a specific Foreign Key.

If I have a Question Model, and I have an Answer Model, and Answer has a Foreign Key to a Question, I want to return the Answer field that corresponds to the Question Foreign key

views.py (right now it returns everything)

```
class FindAnswer(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        answer = Answer.objects.all()
        serializer = AnswerSerializer(answer, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self):
        pass
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Bascially you want to return the answer to a specific question.

Thus on the findAnswer, you need to pass the id number of the question in the get and filter your answers accordingly. however my answer here assumes you could have 0 or more answers.

```
def get(self, request, pk):
    answer = Answer.objects.filter(question__id=pk)
    serializer = AnswerSerilizer(answer, many=True)
    return Response(serilizer.data)
```